# Start a container which runs my shell script but get file not found error

Tags: docker, shell, sh

My project directory structure is like this:

```
myapp/
  Dockerfile
  myscript.sh
```

`myscript.sh` is :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running my tasks..."
```

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM busybox
COPY myscript.sh /myscript.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/myscript.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/myscript.sh" ]
```

I built my image successfully:

```
docker build -t my-app:1.0.0 -f Dockerfile .
```

When I run the container I get error:

```
$ docker run -d my-app:1.0.0
534d564d6f748b99d62fec9d72127bb52a83066a5bb673c69e60b445d89b9e6d
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "myscript.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

Why it can not find `myscript.sh`?

Comment: "*`ENTRYPOINT [ "/myscript.sh" ]`*" - Try using `ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "/myscript.sh" ]`

Comment: What is the very very first line of the script?  (You should not normally need to name an interpreter the way @Turing85 suggests if it begins with a correct `#!/bin/sh` line.)

Comment: I think sh is the default interpreter for scripts though. At least in busybox because its the root users login shell. So while its good practice to have a shebang, neither of the suggestions should be strictly required.

Comment: I just tested it. I cant run a script without shebang in busybox. I wonder why.

Comment: I updated my question with the shell script content, which is just two lines.

Comment: @Turing85 your suggestion actually solved the problem. could you or someone in the discussion please make an answer & elaborate why need to add `"/bin/sh"` as the 1st element in `ENTRYPOINT`?

Comment: @user842225, you can read more about shebang here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/eefd59e28fa2331947237a955da58fd2)

Comment: @Zeitounator, because you have a shebang in your script. Remove it and see it breaks. I am still not sure why. I thought its using the default login shell of the root user, the one thats in /etc/passwd.

Comment: @TheFool there's a shebang in op's script as well in the question.

Comment: @Zeitounator, oh, you are right. That wasn't there at the beginning.